# Unicode character comparison doesn`t work as it should

Tags: python, unicode, compare

Currently I`m working on a program and I have a line where I need to compare a character i with a unicode character "”". It looks like the following:

```
    i != "”"
```

My whole code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


f = open('text.txt', "r")
g = open('write.txt', "w")


for word in f:
  for i in word:
    if all( [i != " ", i != "," ,i != "!", i != "?", i != ";",  
       i !=".", i != ":", i != "”", i != "”" ]):
      g.write(i.lower())
    else:
        g.write('\n
```

The idea is that a text is being parsed and that all characters like dots, points, question marks, etc. are taken out. The only problem is that the unicode character ” will not be taken out of the text. Could you guys give me a hand in this? Thanks!

For your information I`m using python 2.7.11+

Comment: what is the content of text.txt ??

Comment: It is just plain text that is being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `i != "”"`, neither `i` nor `"”"` are Unicode strings. If you want to compare Unicode characters, and you know that `test.txt` is encoded in `utf-8`, try this:

```
for i in word.decode('utf-8'):
    if i != u"”":
```

Not directly related to your question, it might be easier to use `in` than `all()`:

```
if i not in u" ,!?;.:”":
```

Here is a tested example program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


f = open('text.txt', "r")
g = open('write.txt', "w")


for word in f:
  for i in word.decode('utf-8'):
    if i not in u" ,!?;.:”":
      g.write(i.lower())
    else:
      g.write('\n')
```

Input `text.txt`:

```
hello.zippy”
goodbye
```

Output `write.txt`:

```
hello
zippy

goodbye
```

Comment: I get an error:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Rob was not complete. I had to put this at the beginning of the file:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Now everything works like a charm! :D